# Python Pandas Dataframes: Can't Conditionally Delete Rows, Always Delete Entire Dataset on Accident

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For over two hours, I have not been able to solve this problem. I've found every single variation of a solution it seems, but none of them seem to work. It may be because I'm running on four hours of sleep per day, though. Anyway, what I'm trying to do is conditionally delete rows from a pandas dataframe. The dataframe is from a trending youtube videos CSV. One of the columns is "category_id."

I'm trying to remove all categories that do not have the number 25 or 43. Everytime I do this, the entire dataset is reduced down to 0 rows. I know what you're thinking, do rows exist that even have category 25 or 43? YES! They do!

A solution I really thought would work is as follows:

```
df.drop(df[df.category_id != 25].index, inplace=True)
df.drop(df[df.category_id != 43].index, inplace=True)
```

But then I inspect that dataframe and it is empty. How to fix this?

Comment: Can you spend a minute to create a sample dataset, and copy-pasteable Python code to run? It would only need three or four rows to be very helpful.

Comment: `df = df.loc[df['category_id].isin([25, 43])]` will keep only (25, 43) category_id's. If category_id is a string type column, use `.isin(['25', '43'])` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
df = pd.DataFrame( {'category_id': [12, 14, 25, 7, 29, 43, 22, 95]} )
df
        category_id
   0    12
   1    14
   2    25
   3    7
   4    29
   5    43
   6    22
   7    95

   df.drop( list(df[ ~ df['category_id'].isin([25, 43])].index), \
                 inplace = True, axis = 0)
   df

   category_id
   2    25
   4    43
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you're removing all the category_ids that aren't equal to 43, and then removing all the category_ids that aren't equal to 25. Leaving you with an empty dataframe.

I think it would be easier for you to find the indexes you would like to drop and then remove those from your dataframe.

```
indexes = df[df['category_id'] != 25 & df['category_id'] != 40].index
df = df.drop(indexes)
```

Comment: With this, I get "the truth value of a series is ambiguous" and the code does not run.

I tried replacing it with
```
indexes = df[df['category_id'] != 25].index
indexes2 = df[df['category_id'] != 43].index
df = df.drop(indexes, axis=1)
df = df.drop(indexes2, axis=1)
```
but that again resulted in an empty dataframe